# How do I avoid forward declarations?

Tags: c++, c++11

Let's say I have two classes, A and B:

```
class B;

class A
{
private:
    int an_int;
    B *something_else;
public:
    A(int n) : an_int(n), something_else(nullptr) {}
};

class B
{
private:
    int an_int;
    A *something_else;
public:
    B(int n) : an_int(n), something_else(nullptr) {}
};
```

How can I make it so that I don't have to prototype B in order to have a pointer to a B object in class A?

Comment: You can't. Why do you want to avoid forward declarations? They exist precisely for this scenario.

Comment: I see. I'm helping a few friends out on a CS assignment about inheritance and the prof made explicit instructions to not use forward decs. The situation is similar to what's asked in here. I guess they'll have to let him know that it's not exactly possible without prototyping...

Comment: I presume you are aware that your example doesn't in fact use inheritance.

Comment: Make type B a template parameter?

Answer (score 3):

This solution is most probably what is intended in an exercise about inheritance where you can't use a forward declaration.

Instead of the forward declaration

```
class B;
```

you can define an interface like

```
struct I_whoop
{
    virtual void whoop_whoop() = 0;
};
```

then let class B implement that interface, and just use a pointer to the interface.

Answer (score 1):

Actually You can not if using concrete class.
But You can achieve your goal by using template parameters. Making class B a template parameter of template class A.

Answer (score 0):

> How can I make it so that I don't have to prototype B in order to have a pointer to a B object in class A?

Like this:

```
class A
{
private:
    int an_int;
    class B *something_else;
public:
    A(int n) : an_int(n), something_else(nullptr) {}
};

class B
{
private:
    int an_int;
    class A *something_else;
public:
    B(int n) : an_int(n), something_else(nullptr) {}
};
```

In C and C++ it has never been necessary for a type `T` to be
forward declared before the declaration of objects of type `T *`
(or `const` variants), because the declaration of a `T *` *per se* requires
the compiler only to know the size of a `T *`, not the size or definition
of a `T`, and the size of a `T *` is the same, regardless of `T`.

Here is a more fleshed-out illustration:

```
class A
{
private:
    int an_int;
    class B *something_else;
public:
    A(int n, class B * pb = nullptr) : an_int(n), something_else(pb) {}
    int get_int() const {
        return an_int;
    }
    void set_B(class B * pb) {
        something_else = pb;
    }   
    class B * get_B() const {
        return something_else;
    }
};

class B
{
private:
    int an_int;
    class A *something_else;
public:
    B(int n, class A * pa = nullptr) : an_int(n), something_else(pa) {}
    int get_int() const {
        return an_int;
    }
    void set_A(class A * pa) {
        something_else = pa;
    }   
    class A * get_A() const {
        return something_else;
    }
};

#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    A a(1);
    B b(2);
    a.set_B(&b);
    b.set_A(&a);

    std::cout << a.get_B()->get_int() << std::endl; 
    std::cout << b.get_A()->get_int() << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
2
1
```

(gcc 4.9.2/clang 3.5.2 -std=c++11 -Wall -pedantic)

Comment: It is mostly a forward declaration in-place.